# Laravel - filter collection and then ->toJson, having a minor issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel controller which takes a search parameter, looks through all the records in a certain time range, uses the laravel collection `->filter` method, and then on the results of that filter method, returns the json `->json`

```
$logs = RequestLog::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->get();
$logs = $logs->filter(function($log) { /* my own logic in here */ });
return response()->json($logs->toJson());
```

Now this seems to work just fine. It normally returns an array of the matching records, `[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]`

But if the `->filter` function leaves one result, let's say the 25th record in the array, the response now comes out like this: `{25: {"id": 25}}`. It ruins the normal array structure and returns a JSON object with a single key.

Is this expected? What's up with this? How do I deal with this?

Note: my `filter` function cannot be done via sql means, it has to be done in PHP.

[edit] it's actually returning an Object JSON anytime the `filter` results are anything other than the **first** items in the original Query results.

Comment: What laravel version is this? You may want to edit your question and add the version tag to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally after applying methods that modifies (especially removes an item from) a collection, the indexes may not come ordered. This is why you need `->values()` on the collection.

So you'd have:

```
return response()->json($logs->values()->toJson());
```

> `values()` Resets the keys on the underlying array.