# Laravel chunk on collection return first element as arrays and second as object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I get all the records from a model, but i need to take chunks from it, i only need the values of the `email` so i map it

```
$forwadings = \App\Models\ForwardingEmail::where('company_id', $companyId)
->where('status', 1)
->get(['email']);
->map(function($forwarding) {
    return $forwarding['email'];
})
return $forwadings;
```

the return display this

```
[
  "email12@example.com",
  "email13@example.com",
  "email1@example.com",
  "email2@example.com",
  "email3@example.com",
  "email6@example.com",
  "email7@example.com",
  "email8@example.com",
  "email4@example.com",
  "email5@example.com",
  "email9@example.com",
  "email10@example.com"
]
```

the problem here is when i do `return $forwardings->chunk(10)`, it show this:

```
[
  [
    "email12@example.com",
    "email13@example.com",
    "email1@example.com",
    "email2@example.com",
    "email3@example.com",
    "email6@example.com",
    "email7@example.com",
    "email8@example.com",
    "email4@example.com",
    "email5@example.com"
  ],
  {
    "10": "email9@example.com",
    "11": "email10@example.com"
  }
]
```

why this happens? and how can i solve this? i tried using `toArray` on the chunk result but did not work. i am using laravel 5.3

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? Because, I thought I'd try and reproduce this but for me, on 5.5 and 6.x your solution works. As in, both chunks are collections, and toArray returns an array of two arrays...

Comment: Was able to reproduce using `toJson` both on 5.5 and 6.x.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back, see if the answer there is relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935133/laravel-filter-collection-and-then-tojson-having-a-minor-issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Laravel's `->chunk()` method applies an incrementing `id` to all chunked items.  When converting to JSON, this is an issue because JavaScript does not allow arrays to start with offset key values (not starting with 0), therefore they must be defined as objects.

You can do your own processing to remove the key values. Something like this should work.

```php
$chunks = \App\Models\ForwardingEmail::where('company_id', $companyId)
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->pluck('email')
    ->chunk(10);

foreach ($chunks as $key => $chunk) {
    $chunks[$key] = array_values($chunk->toArray());
}

return $chunks;
```

Comment: This is something new for me as well. Thanks

Comment: Can confirm this behaviour, ended up using plain arrays but was a bit of a pain to realize the error.

Answer (score 7):

I know its bit late and it already has an answer. I came to this question when I was searching for a way to reset the keys of each chunk when using chunk method. In my case my models were also loaded with relations so for me it was important to keep the entities as objects rather than arrays. But `array_values` did not work for me, instead collection's `values` method was the one which worked for me. Sharing this answer just to help those who are visiting this page in search for an answer the way I reached here.

Here is what worked for me applied to this question.

```
$chunks = \App\Models\ForwardingEmail::where('company_id', $companyId)
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->pluck('email')
    ->chunk(10);

$chunks = $chunks->map(function($chunk) {
   return $chunk = $chunk->values();
});

return $chunks;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `pluck`

```
$forwadings = \App\Models\ForwardingEmail::where('company_id', $companyId)
->where('status', 1)
->pluck('email')->toArray();
```

Comment: i need the array chunked, the pluck worked as a sustitute for the map, but when i try to chunk get the same result, an array and a object.